# Transform HH MM SS in seconds

Tags: javascript

I need to transform 3 form inputs (HH, MM, SS) in seconds with javascript.

I have this code but it has only with 1 form input in seconds : https://jsfiddle.net/94150148/hhomeLc3/

To do this I need a new javascript function.

```
window.onload = function () {generate()};

function generate() {

var width = 'width=\"' + document.getElementById('width').value + '\" ';
var height = 'height=\"' + document.getElementById('height').value + '\" ';
var ytid = "videoID";
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

if (start !== "") {
    if(ytid === document.getElementById('ytid')) {
        ytid += '?start=' + start;
    }
    else {
        ytid += '&start=' + start;
    }
}
if (end !== "") {
    if (ytid === document.getElementById('ytid')) {
        ytid += '?end=' + end;
    }
    else {
        ytid += '&end=' + end;
    }
}
document.getElementById('embedcode').value = '<iframe ' + width + height +
'src=\"https://www.youtube.com\/embed\/' + ytid +
'\" frameborder=\"0\"><\/iframe>';
}

function clearall() {   
document.getElementById('width').value = 550;
document.getElementById('height').value = 315;
document.getElementById('start').value = "";
document.getElementById('end').value = "";
}
```

The jsFiddle to play with what I need : https://jsfiddle.net/94150148/ybmkcyyu/

Comment: hummm, I'm not sure I understand your needs... But hhmmss can be converted to seconds by just using : `ss + 60 * (mm + 60 * hh))`, no?

Comment: Yes but being newbie in javascript, I do not know how to code this.

Comment: @Laurent, time to hire someone to do this for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ybmkcyyu/3/

EDIT: 
Do not display start and end when value is 0
https://jsfiddle.net/ybmkcyyu/6/

EDIT2: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ybmkcyyu/7/

```
if (start !== "") {
    ytid += '?start=' + start;
}
if (end !== "") {
    if (start == "") {
        ytid += '?end=' + end;
    }
    else {
  ytid += '&end=' + end;
    }
}
```

You just need to get value of every fields, as int, then add it with the formula: ((hours * 60) + minutes ) * 60 + secondes
And you might ensure that the result is a number. (if user enter a char instead of a number, it should not display something wrong)

```
var starth = parseInt(document.getElementById('starth').value);
var startm = parseInt(document.getElementById('startm').value);
var starts = parseInt(document.getElementById('starts').value);
var endh = parseInt(document.getElementById('endh').value);
var endm = parseInt(document.getElementById('endm').value);
var ends = parseInt(document.getElementById('ends').value);

var start = (((starth * 60) + startm) * 60) + starts;
if(isNaN(start) || start === 0)
   start = "";
var end = (((endh * 60) + endm) * 60) + ends;
if(isNaN(end) || end === 0)
  end = "";

/* (...) */
```

Comment: Thanks @didier it is ok but to comlete this if the h m s values are 0 i need to no display &start=0 and &end=0

Comment: Just updated the answer. You need to add in: if(isNaN(start)) the condition: or start == 0, which is in javascript the syntax: if(isNaN(start) || start === 0) { } (same thing with end.)

Comment: Thank you @didier it is almost perfect, there is just a small problem, the first parameter after the the youtube video id, must always begin by ?start = or ?end = and then it is with the &

Comment: Thank you it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

JS is generally quite good at math.

```
sHour = document.getElementById('starth').value,
sMin = document.getElementById('startm').value,
sSec = document.getElementById('starts').value,
sTime = (sHour * 3600) + (sMin * 60) + sSec;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/ybmkcyyu/4/